# python pandas repeat cells from column and concatenate

Tags: python, pandas, repeat

I Have a Dataframe like this :

```
***Out[112]:*** 
  Cell Name   Site  Cell Count
0    04301A  04301           3
1    04301B  04301           3
2    04301C  04301           3
3    04302A  04302           3
4    04302B  04302           3
5    04302C  04302           3
6    04303A  04303           2
7    04303B  04303           2
8    04304A  04304           3
```

and I want to repeat the 'Cell Name' Column by the 'Cell Count' Column then concatenate the each cell name with other cell names in the same Site so the output will be like this :

```
***Out[119]:*** 
  Repeated Cells   Site  Cell-Neighbor
0         04301A  04301  04301A-04301B
1         04301A  04301  04301A-04301C
2         04301B  04301  04301B-04301A
3         04301B  04301  04301B-04301C
4         04301C  04301  04301C-04301A
5         04301C  04301  04301C-04301B
6         04302A  04302  04302A-04302B
7         04302A  04302  04302A-04302C
8         04302B  04302  04302B-04302A
9         04302B  04302  04302B-04302C
```

I managed to repeat the cells and put theme in a new DataFrame using the following line

```
repeated_cells = df_gcell['Cell Name'].repeat(df_gcell['Cell Count'] - 1).values
```

I subtracted (1) from the count because I don't need the cell to be concatenated with it self,

my problem now is how to import other cells from the same Site and concatenate them with the cell!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- looking at your input and output it's clear you require **permutations** with a *Site*
- to simplify a little,  target column names I have defined without spaces in them
- your data fro **Site 04304** is inconsistent so gets dropped

```
import io
import itertools

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""  Cell Name   Site  Cell Count
0    04301A  04301           3
1    04301B  04301           3
2    04301C  04301           3
3    04302A  04302           3
4    04302B  04302           3
5    04302C  04302           3
6    04303A  04303           2
7    04303B  04303           2
8    04304A  04304           3"""),sep="\s\s+",engine="python",)

df.groupby("Site", as_index=False).agg(
    CellNeighbor=(
        "Cell Name",
        lambda s: ["-".join(c) for c in itertools.permutations(s, 2)],
    )
).explode("CellNeighbor").dropna().assign(
    RepeatedCells=lambda d: d["CellNeighbor"].str.split("-").str[0]
)
```

#### output

|  | Site | CellNeighbor | RepeatedCells |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4301 | 04301A-04301B | 04301A |
| 0 | 4301 | 04301A-04301C | 04301A |
| 0 | 4301 | 04301B-04301A | 04301B |
| 0 | 4301 | 04301B-04301C | 04301B |
| 0 | 4301 | 04301C-04301A | 04301C |
| 0 | 4301 | 04301C-04301B | 04301C |
| 1 | 4302 | 04302A-04302B | 04302A |
| 1 | 4302 | 04302A-04302C | 04302A |
| 1 | 4302 | 04302B-04302A | 04302B |
| 1 | 4302 | 04302B-04302C | 04302B |
| 1 | 4302 | 04302C-04302A | 04302C |
| 1 | 4302 | 04302C-04302B | 04302C |
| 2 | 4303 | 04303A-04303B | 04303A |
| 2 | 4303 | 04303B-04303A | 04303B |

Comment: i also did it now with 3 for loops: